# How to re-analyze complete history of a project using Sonar?

Tags: svn, version-control, statistics, history, sonarqube

I would like to load the entire project history since its inception into Sonar.

I would basically want to execute code like this:

```
0) checkout version 1 from Subversion
1) checkout next version from Subversion
2) if the commit date is from the same day as the previous one - goto 1
3) run mvn sonar:sonar, overriding the build time with the time of the commit
4) if not on last commit - goto 1
```

Is there a tool that does this already? Is there a way of convincing Sonar to use a different date than the current one?

Comment: I have the same question and I'm very interested about a script with the "sonar.projectDate". Did you write this script ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is from the Mailing Lists:

Indeed, to import historical data you must use the "sonar.projectDate" property (Format is yyyy-MM-dd, for example 2010-12-25) [1] and launch a Sonar analysis on each tag/branch that you'd like to see in your project history.

http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/re-ordering-historical-data-td3191565.html

There is an additional [Blogpost](http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-time-machine-replaying-the-past/) that explains this further.

Answer (score 1):

I was just searching for this exact same thing and found a handy bash script in GitHub:

https://gist.github.com/aslakknutsen/2422117

The script does a checkout of each tag (beginning from a specific tag given as a parameter), sets the tag date as sonar.projectDate and runs sonar analysis on it. Very handy. I think I might have to modify it a little bit since we don't have that much tags in the repo, maybe do a weekly analysis or something.

Answer (score 1):

Python tool to load a snapshot for every month/week since a given date.

https://gist.github.com/Cassus/6229929

Answer (score 1):

Just find out the script from [@adam-banko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424402/adam-banko) does not work for me anymore (since it is 8 years old).

Here is an updated Python3 script to upload historical snapshots of maven project:
https://gist.github.com/hughluo/c51b14cfcd9afe3f89149f478c1a65d5

### Usage

1. Change the date range in the script to fit your needs.
2. Put the script in the folder where your project root `pom.xml` located in and run

```
SONAR_HOST=<sonar.host.url> SONAR_LOGIN=<sonar.login> SONAR_PROJECT=<sonar.projectKey> python3 upload_snapshots_sonar.py
```